# Calculating a sum including large numbers

Tags: co.combinatorics, na.numerical-analysis

Let

$\theta(x)=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x<0 \\ 
1 & \text{ if } x\ge 0 
\end{cases}$

Do you know any way to calculate this number:

$$\sum_{r=493701}^{506199}\sum_{k=0}^{100}(-1)^k\frac{\binom{100}{k}\binom{r-10001k+99}{99}\theta(r-10001k+99)}{\binom{r+99}{r}}$$
or estimate it within 0.01. Gap and wolfram failed to calculate it. Also [octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) seems to be unable to calculate it.

Comment: I have asked [it](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1430554/calculating-a-sum-which-includes-binomial-coeffeicients/1430575#1430575) in MSE.

Comment: Why do you need this particular number?

Comment: I encountered it when solving a problem.

Comment: There are only about $1.2$ million terms. Is the problem that there is nearly exact cancelation?

Comment: Yes there many terms. I have no problem if it takes an app a few days to calculate it. But I didn't find such an app.

Comment: Again, what is the difficulty in this calculation? If you separate the positive terms and the negative terms, and ask Mathematica to evaluate each piece to $100$ digits, what do you get? Do the pieces agree to $100$ digits or something like that? If you haven't tried things like that, then you should do so to make sure it isn't a large but straightforward calculation.

Comment: Separating will not help, except complicating calculations, because partial sums will be larger. I have also simplified the binomial coeffecients but still I get no results in the open-source or open access calculating apps I knew.

Comment: Again, you have not explained how this is not a straightforward computation. If it is a straightforward computation but just moderately large, that is not a research-level question. It sounds like you probably are making some elementary errors that you gloss over by saying "Gap and Wolfram failed."

Comment: So this would look quite a lot easier if you removed the theta. For r in the range 493701 to 499950, k ranges from 0 to 49 (inside this range theta is 1; outside it's 0). For r in the range 499951 to 506199, k ranges from 0 to 50.

Comment: I have not tested it. But gap result says `<integer 714...349 (28661 digits)>/<integer 547...000 (28670 digits)>`. So I don't think this will help.

Comment: Why not try to get an estimate by replacing sums with integrals and binomials with quotients and products of gamma functions? Maybe it is possible to estimate the error and see if the precision suffices.

Comment: @user47958: But that means that GAP has computed the result. -- To see it, just use the function 'Display' or 'Print'; thus if you enter Display(last); just after the result you cite, you will see the number.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because after the OP's last comment, answering it amounts to simple advice on using GAP.

Comment: with mpmath I compute  the sum. It is equal to 0.0000000013060480365934635751811931267930306865307928780

Comment: @juan: I don't know pmmath. What's the code you gave mpmath?

Comment: @user47958 I computed each term with 500 digits. After some experiments with the terms I saw this more than sufficient. Then added the terms one by one. The code is very simple but too long for a comment. Send me an email if you want the code.

Comment: @jaun: I sent an email (jee..ve.com).

Comment: @StefanKohl: I know about display or print. How can I get that long frac calculated? I tried a code to calclate it but it printed `-nan`.

Comment: @user47958: You have a rational which is the exact value -- what else do you need?

Comment: its decimal approximation.

Comment: Note that for k > 25 the terms seem to be smaller than (100 choose 25)*(2^{-99}), which should be small enough for the desired precision.  So only 300,000 terms need be computed.  Further, for fixed r, the sum is alternating , so pick k which yields the desired tolerance, perhaps k=20.  Gerhard "Why Add Zero To Zero?" Paseman, 2015.09.12

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By comments after adding mpmath package to python one can run this program to see the result:

```
from mpmath import *
mp.dps=50

def th(x):
    if x<0:
        return 0
    else:
        return 1


def f(r,k):
    a=(-1)**k*binomial(100,k)*binomial(r-10001*k+99,99)*th(r-10001*k+99)
    a= a/binomial(r+99,r)
    return a

from timeit import default_timer as clock
time0 = clock()

s=0
for r in range(493701,506200):
    for k in range(0,101):
        s=s+ f(r,k)
time1 = clock()
print 'The result is'
print s
print 'computed in ', round(time1-time0,3), 'sec'


"""
Result:
0.0000000013060480365934635751811931267930306865307928

"""
```

mpmath is available in Ubuntu repository. Also one can write a C++ program using [GMP](https://gmplib.org/): http://rextester.com/TGS53335 (this can be run only in a local computer with gmb installed and `-lgmb` library introduced to the compiler).

Gap can calculate to a fraction but cannot show the decimal representation.

Comment: Are you sure that is a limitation of GAP as opposed to something you just don't yet know how to do in GAP? I would bet on the latter. http://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap19.html

Comment: @DouglasZare give me a working code instead of broadcasting news about you bet on. There is a seemingly unofficial  FUtil package for gap which may produce the result I did not test it. I have searched internet and used anything I found. If there anything else then I bet that gap with such poor documentation developed with such bad command formation does not deserve anyone's betting.

Comment: This is a site for the discussion of research level mathematics, not a site for the discussion of your problems with the documentation of a particular program or for you to demand that people give you working code.

Comment: @DouglasZare: Gap can show the decimal representation of a fraction. But it could not show the decimal representation of the question's calculation. If you have code that GAP has calculated and shown the decimal representation of the calculations above give the code. give the code. " I explained how you could do the calculation" really? where?  You did not give me any calculating code in Gap or wolfram? did you? Just you informed me about what you felt about the question.

Comment: So I can bet that GAP, the version I have installed, is unable to show the decimal rep. If you give me a working code, which I no longer need, I will comment out that part in the answer.

Comment: a few comments were deleted by moderators.